# JFlex match nested comments as one token

Tags: comments, grammar, lex, jflex

In Mathematica a comment starts with `(*` and ends with `*)` and comments can be nested. My current approach of scanning a comment with JFlex contains the following code

```
%xstate IN_COMMENT

"(*"  { yypushstate(IN_COMMENT); return MathematicaElementTypes.COMMENT;}

<IN_COMMENT> {
  "(*"        {yypushstate(IN_COMMENT); return MathematicaElementTypes.COMMENT;}
  [^\*\)\(]*  {return MathematicaElementTypes.COMMENT;}
  "*)"        {yypopstate(); return MathematicaElementTypes.COMMENT;}
  [\*\)\(]    {return MathematicaElementTypes.COMMENT;}
  .           {return MathematicaElementTypes.BAD_CHARACTER;}
}
```

where the methods `yypushstate` and `yypopstate` are defined as

```
private final LinkedList<Integer> states = new LinkedList();

private void yypushstate(int state) {
    states.addFirst(yystate());
    yybegin(state);
}
private void yypopstate() {
    final int state = states.removeFirst();
    yybegin(state);
}
```

to give me the opportunity to track how many nested levels of comment I'm dealing with.

Unfortunately, this results in several `COMMENT` tokens for one comment, because I have to match nested comment starts and comment ends.

**Question:** Is it possible with JFlex to use its API with methods like `yypushback` or `advance()` etc. to return exactly one token over the whole comment range, even if comments are nested?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems the bounty was uncalled for as the solution is so simple that I just did not consider it. Let me explain. When scanning a simple nested comment

```
(* (*..*) *)
```

I have to track, how many opening comment tokens I see so that I finally, on the last real closing comment can return the whole comment as one token.

What I did not realise was, that JFlex does not need to be told to *advance* to the next portion when it matches something. After careful review I saw that this is [explained here](http://jflex.de/manual.html#ExampleLexRules) but somewhat hidden in a section I didn't care for:

> Because we do not yet return a value to the parser, our scanner proceeds immediately.

Therefore, a rule in `flex` file like this

```
[^\(\*\)]+ { }
```

reads all characters except those that could probably be a comment start/end and does nothing **but it advances to the next token**.

This means that I can simply do the following. In the `YYINITIAL` state, I have a rule that matches a beginning comment but it does nothing else then switch the lexer to the `IN_COMMENT` state. In particular, it does not return any token:

```
{CommentStart}      { yypushstate(IN_COMMENT);}
```

Now, we are in the `IN_COMMENT` state and there, I do the same. I eat up all characters but never return a token. When I hit a new opening comment, I carefully push it onto a stack but do nothing. Only, when I hit the **last** closing comment, I know I'm leaving the `IN_COMMENT` state and this is the only point, where I, finally, return the token. Let's look at the rules:

```
<IN_COMMENT> {
  {CommentStart}  { yypushstate(IN_COMMENT);}
  [^\(\*\)]+      { }
  {CommentEnd}    {  yypopstate();
                     if(yystate() != IN_COMMENT)
                       return MathematicaElementTypes.COMMENT_CONTENT;
                  }
    [\*\)\(]      { }
    .             { return MathematicaElementTypes.BAD_CHARACTER; }
}
```

That's it. Now, no matter how deep your comment is nested, you will always get one single token that contains the entire comment.

Now, I'm embarrassed and I'm sorry for such a simple question.

### Final note

If you are doing something like this, you have to remember that you only return a token from when you hit the correct closing "character". Therefore, you definitely should make a rule that catches the end of file. In IDEA that default behavior is to just return the comment token, so you need another line (useful or not, I want to end gracefully):

```
    <<EOF>>  { yyclearstack(); yybegin(YYINITIAL);
               return MathematicaElementTypes.COMMENT;}
```

Answer (score 2):

When I wrote the answer first I had even not realized that one of the existing answers was of the questioner itself. On the other hand, I seldom find a bounty in the rather small SO lex community. Thus, this seemed to me worth to learn enough Java and jflex to write a sample:

```
/* JFlex scanner: to recognize nested comments in Mathematica style
 */

%%

%{
  /* counter for open (nested) comments */
  int open = 0;
%}

%state IN_COMMENT

%%

/* any state */

"(*" { if (!open++) yybegin(IN_COMMENT); }

"*)" { 
    if (open) {
      if (!--open) {
        yybegin(YYINITIAL);
        return MathematicaElementTypes.COMMENT;
      }
    } else {
      /* or return MathematicaElementTypes.BAD_CHARACTER;
      /* or: throw new Error("'*)' without '(*'!"); */
    }
  }

<IN_COMMENT> {
  . |
  \n { }
}

<<EOF>> {
    if (open) {
      /* This is obsolete if the scanner is instanced new for
       * each invocation.
       */
      open = 0; yybegin(IN_COMMENT);
      /* Notify about syntax error, e.g. */
      throw new Error("Premature end of file! ("
        + open + " open comments not closed.)");
    }
    return MathematicaElementTypes.EOF; /* just a guess */
  }
```

There might be typos and stupid errors although I tried to be carefully and did my best.

As a "proof of concept" I leave my original implementation here which is done with flex and C/C++.

This scanner

- handles comment (with `printf()`)
- echoes everything else.

My solution is essentially based on the fact that flex rules may end with `break` or `return`. Therefore, the token is simply not returned until the rule for the pattern is matched closing the outmost comment. Contents in comments is simply "recorded" in a buffer – in my case a `std::string`.
(AFAIK, `string` is even a built-in type in Java. Therefore, I decided to mix C and C++ which I usally wouldn't.)

My source `scan-nested-comments.l`:

```
%{
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>

// counter for open (nested) comments
static int open = 0;
// buffer for collected comments
static std::string comment;
%}

/* make never interactive (prevent usage of certain C functions) */
%option never-interactive
/* force lexer to process 8 bit ASCIIs (unsigned characters) */
%option 8bit
/* prevent usage of yywrap */
%option noyywrap

%s IN_COMMENT

%%

"(*" {
  if (!open++) BEGIN(IN_COMMENT);
  comment += "(*";
}

"*)" {
  if (open) {
    comment += "*)";
    if (!--open) {
      BEGIN(INITIAL);
      printf("EMIT TOKEN COMMENT(lexem: '%s')\n", comment.c_str());
      comment.clear();
    }
  } else {
    printf("ERROR: '*)' without '(*'!\n");
  }
}

<IN_COMMENT>{
  . |
  "\n" { comment += *yytext; }
}

<<EOF>> {
  if (open) {
    printf("ERROR: Premature end of file!\n"
      "(%d open comments not closed.)\n", open);
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

%%

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  if (argc > 1) {
    yyin = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (!yyin) {
      printf("Cannot open file '%s'!\n", argv[1]);
      return 1;
    }
  } else yyin = stdin;
  return yylex();
}
```

I compiled it with flex and g++ in cygwin on Windows 10 (64 bit):

```
$ flex -oscan-nested-comments.cc scan-nested-comments.l ; g++ -o scan-nested-comments scan-nested-comments.cc
scan-nested-comments.cc:398:0: warning: "yywrap" redefined

 ^
scan-nested-comments.cc:74:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition

 ^

$
```

The warning appears due to `%option noyywrap`. I guess it does not mean any harm and can be ignored.

Now, I made some tests:

```
$ cat >good-text.txt <<EOF
> Test for nested comments.
> (* a comment *)
> (* a (* nested *) comment *)
> No comment.
> (* a
> (* nested
> (* multiline *)
>  *)
>  comment *)
> End of file.
> EOF

$ cat good-text | ./scan-nested-comments
Test for nested comments.
EMIT TOKEN COMMENT(lexem: '(* a comment *)')

EMIT TOKEN COMMENT(lexem: '(* a (* nested *) comment *)')

No comment.
EMIT TOKEN COMMENT(lexem: '(* a
(* nested
(* multiline *)
 *)
 comment *)')

End of file.

$ cat >bad-text-1.txt <<EOF
> Test for wrong comment.
> (* a comment *)
> with wrong nesting *)
> End of file.
> EOF

$ cat >bad-text-1.txt | ./scan-nested-comments
Test for wrong comment.
EMIT TOKEN COMMENT(lexem: '(* a comment *)')

with wrong nesting ERROR: '*)' without '(*'!

End of file.

$ cat >bad-text-2.txt <<EOF
> Test for wrong comment.
> (* a comment
> which is not closed.
> End of file.
> EOF

$ cat >bad-text-2.txt | ./scan-nested-comments
Test for wrong comment.
ERROR: Premature end of file!
(1 open comments not closed.)

$
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. After reading it, I became aware that I missed mentioning one important point in my answer (and the question). I'm using jflex for an IntelliJ IDEA plugin which is implemented with a so-called JFlex Adaper. Therefore, I never need to return strings, just the tokens itself. Besides this and the fact that I'm using a stack for counting how many nested levels I'm in, our approaches are similar and it seems I haven't done any stupid mistake.

Comment: Anyway, thank you very much for doing it not in Java but in C since it really adds value for future visitors. Since my answer solves my direct problem, I will mark it as accepted, but I'm more than happy that I can give you the bounty and that the reputation is not lost in /dev/null. +1 btw.

Comment: Thanks for the bounty which appeared just when I tried to port my sample to Java/jflex. As mentioned it should be taken "with a grain of salt".

Answer (score -1):

The Java traditional comment is defined in the sample grammar with

```
TraditionalComment   = "/*" [^*] ~"*/" | "/*" "*"+ "/"
```

I suppose this expression should work for Mathematica comments too.

Comment: Java's block comments are non-nesting, so I don't think it would solve the original question.